# Complexity of generating power sets

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes

Suppose I have two sets $A$ and $B$ containing integers. Let $B'$ be the power set of $B$. Then suppose I have an algorithm that enumerates all possible pairings of elements in $A$ and $B'$ to apply a function $f$ to them and check something.

I understand that generating a power set is $O(2^n)$, but what complexity class does this belong to, and how do I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Complexity time $O(2^n)$ is called $\text{DTIME}(O(2^n))$ and is a sub-complexity class of [E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(complexity)) which is in turn a sub-complexity class of [EXPTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME).

To prove you can do it within $O(2^n)$ time, you have to provide an algorithm for that and show the algorithm runs in no more than $O(2^n)$.